# Ubuntu 18 - how to ungroup apps in dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

I want to make Ubuntu dock like Windows taskbar

Ubuntu:

[image]

Windows:

[image]

(as you see Windows has three **Explorer** icons and Ubuntu has only one **Files** icon

Is it possible to uncombine/ungroup apps in Ubuntu?

Comment: I didn't found a way for the dock, but fot alt + tab you can follow this https://superuser.com/a/860001/914650

Comment: I want this too!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To mimic the Windows taskbar, install the extension ["Dash to Panel"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). It immediately provides a Windows style bar at the bottom of the screen. It has plenty of configuration options, including the option you are after, i.e., ungrouping application buttons. 'Dash to Panel" is an excellent extension.

Comment: This is the amazing!  You have made my life 10x easier with this plugin! I can confirm this works great with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: After installation (at `https://extensions.gnome.org/`), the setting is found at `Behaviour/Ungroup applications` (Dash-to-Panel version: 23).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me! And the app settings allow much more options than the regular Windows panel. The only thing I can't do is drag it by mouse to change it width...

Comment: It still doesn't fix the window+num shortcut. Separate windows of the same app share the same number. Any fix for this?

Comment: this extension is nice. Liked the multi monitor options.

Answer (score 15):

in Ubuntu 20.04,

###### Install `gnome tweaks` and `dash to panel extension`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel
```

###### Then, restart PC/Laptop.

1. Open `Tweaks` -> go to `Extensions`
2. Enable `Dash to panel`
3. In `Dash to panel` -> click `Settings` Icon
4. In `Behavior` tab, enable `Ungroup applications`
5. In `Ungroup applications` -> click `Settings` Icon
6. Set `Maximum width` -> 0 (zero)

`Dash to panel:`
[image: Dash to panel]

`Ungroup Applications:`
[image: Ungroup Applications]

`Hide label:`
[image: Hide label]

Thanks to @vanadium and @moony

Comment: Thank you for the detail.

Answer (score 4):

Follow up for previous answers. To install `Dash to Panel` extension (and others extensions) in **Ubuntu 22.04** at first there is a need to install standalone `Extension Manager` (since installing extensions in Firefox is not working):

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`

source - [Install Gnome Shell Extensions 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404497/install-gnome-shell-extensions-22-04-lts)

After that it is possible to run `Extension Manager` app and inside it to find and install `Dash to Panel` extension.

Comment: Beware. While this works (i.e. I can access the settings), it always crashes when selecting "ungroup buttons" or however it's called. One has to disable the extension and re-log in in order to make the system usable again.

Comment: @MikhailOrlov, yes, in Ubuntu 22.04 `Dash to Panel` extension works badly - there is bugs now. I returned to Ubuntu 20.04. On it this extension works normally.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to retract my message. Turned out, one has to set 100% width explicitly. Then while there might be a crashing message, it still shows and works. I can live with that.

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 22.04 there is no "apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel", however "Dash to Panel" is installable through the manager; was buggy but works as @MikhailOrlov mentioned with setting 100% (it somehow jumps to 90%). 
Sadly, even though it splits the app icons, it shows them on all monitors, not just the one you've opened the app on.

Comment: Oh, my bad it can, it's under Behavior - "Isolate monitors", there's also "Isolate workspaces"

Comment: If you can't find it in extension manager - try to search exactly `"Dash to Panel" ` (quotes included) and change search filter to "Downloads" or "Recent"... somehow it does not prioritize by exact name match :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a taskbar extension [available](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/).

Unfortunately, the development of that extension was halted on 15 december. However, Dash to Panel fully covers the functionality of Taskbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, the development of that extension was halted on 15 december. However, Dash to Panel fully covers the functionality of Taskbar.