# How to run multiple Firefox/Thunderbird icons on the dock?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, dock, dconf

If I open Firefox or Thunderbird or any other application twice, they stack on top of each other in the dock. I run `GNOME 3.36` on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`.

How can I duplicate the icons of the applications that I open, on the dock?

This is especially useful when using multiple screens, so that I can easily switch between opened apps without having to select which Firefox instance I want to show on the main screen, since the second one always runs on the second screen.

The `dconf-editor` did not seem to have any option that allows me to run multiple icons instead of stacking the icons.

Comment: Dash to Panel may be what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/a/1052673/100356 and https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. Probably the best app I could wish for, to fine control all aspects of the bars.

Comment: Yes like PJ Singh said, Dash to Panel is the solution to this