# Certain applications cannot be reordered in Dash to panel

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I use the Dash-to-Panel extension (see for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1052673/800252) to get a Windows-like toolbar. This should allow either grouping or ungrouping multiple instances of an application and if ungrouped it should allow rearranging their order (after checking that `Lock taskbar` is off). For the most part this works perfectly. However, for at least one application (Mathematica) different instances remain ungrouped when grouping is turned on and worse no matter whether grouping is turned on or not the instances cannot be rearranged.

Dragging them anywhere will not do anything. On the other hand dragging something else to their position does allow that application to take its place moving the Mathematica instance to the left or the right. This however does not allow for any reordering within the Mathematica instances.

What is going on here? Is there any way around this?