# How to install GNOME Shell extensions in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, 22.04

Using [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop) which is for Ubuntu 20.04 (and worked successfully in that version with GNOME version 3.36.8) what are the installation requirements in 22.04 LTS to avoid the following error message?

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host
> connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about
> installing connector

I have taken the step `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell` but to no avail.

The version of GNOME in 22.04 LTS is v42.0.

Have I missed something vital?

Answer (score 20):

Use the Extension Manager instead. It has less steps to getting the extensions compared to getting through the GNOME shell add-on integration with Firefox. You can install it by opening a terminal and running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Once installed, you can use the GUI and search for extensions compatible with 22.04.

**Note:** GNOME extensions can no longer be installed via Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 by default, since Firefox now comes as a snap package.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a share mounted that I'd like to display on the dash (desktop). It appears in the dock but can't find way of showing it using `shell-extension-manager`. I've added `Desktop Icons` to the manager but I don't think that works (yet). Any ideas?

Comment: @24601 click the setting of the desktop icon extension while in the manager, there are  toggles for ext or network drivers to appear on the desktop

Comment: That errors in 22.04. "[...] but there's been a problem: the settings for this extension can't be displayed" The error is "No property border_width on GtBox"

Comment: @24601, if you are using Desktop Icon NG(DING) and running the original theme, reboot should solve the problem. However, if you are not running original theme or running other additional extensions, you might wanna turn them off first as some of them are either still "glitchy" or not supported yet. I am running skeleton extensions now. Only Desk to panel and Desktop Icon NG. I tried running a couple of others prior and had problems.

Comment: No, I'm running it vanilla and reboot has not solved the problem as both extensions available for Desktop Icon are incompatible with this version of Gnome. Other options however do work (such as single click for extensions shared with nautilus) so the `Extensions` tool works. Guess I'll have to wait till some of the apps mature into this version. Thanks anyway 

Comment: I have removed the snap version of Firefox and reinstalled FF via APT. gnome-shell is in place but the Gnome Shell Extension still won't work. I still got the error "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected."

Comment: I used this guide to install FF via APT: [link(https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

The standalone extension manager works great though.

Comment: @NeoRey that would be useful as an answer if you'd care to offer it. I've done just that and it works well. Thanks.