List view task switcher
How can I have a list view task switcher?
I am looking for something similar to what I have on my mac. I've tried rofi but it does not behave like a native task switcher (you still need to press enter to switch windows).
Im using 24.04 ubuntu. Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!!

Maybe https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3569/task-widget/ it would be a good idea to check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404497/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts with it you can find many shell extensions

There is an excellent Gnome Shell extension, Switcher by dlandau which also doubles as an application launcher. It is perfectly integrated into the desktop environment, and works seamlessly and fast. However, also here you need to hit Enter or Space to close the launcher and switch to the selected window. I prefer to use it for several years instead of the application overview.
